# Help Finding the Radak's Introduction to His Commentary on Torah

Tags: commentaries

Rabbi Eliyahu Munk wrote an English translation of various Biblical commentaries called [Hachut Hameshulash](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9657108349): Commentaries on the Torah by Rabbeinu Chananel, Rashbam, Radak & Seforno-4 Vol. Set. ISBN-13: 978-9657108345. ISBN-10: 9657108349.

At the beginning R’ Munk he quotes part of the Radak’s introduction; I assume that R’ Munk means the Radak’s introduction to the commentary on the Chumash. I’m trying to find that introduction. I don’t see it in paper copies of the Mikra’os Gedolos, and when I go to HebrewBooks.Org, I don’t see it in the Radak’s [commentary](http://hebrewbooks.org/40230) there either.

Can anyone tell me where to find the Hebrew original?

Comment: It was first published in this book http://www.bookgallery.co.il/content/english/bookPageSchema.asp?bookpageid=74138&ShowHebrew=1

Comment: https://www.otzar.org/wotzar/book.aspx?102144    Perhaps is it an introduction from the editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is printed in the מוסד הרב קוק Chumash, תורת חיים, volume one.